# RxJS: Producer-consumer with abort

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I've got a special producer consumer problem in RxJS: The producer slowly produces elements. A consumer is requesting elements and often has to wait for the producer. This can be achieved by zipping the producer and the request stream:

```
var produce = getProduceStream();
var request = getRequestStream();

var consume = Rx.Observable.zipArray(produce, request).pluck(0);
```

Sometimes a request gets aborted. A produced element should only consumed after a not aborted request:

```
produce:  -------------p1-------------------------p2--------->
request:  --r1--------------r2---------------r3-------------->
abort:    ------a(r1)------------------a(?)------------------>
consume:  ------------------c(p1, r2)-------------c(p2, r3)-->
```

The first request `r1` would consume the first produced element `p1`, but `r1` gets aborted by `a(r1)` before it can consume `p1`. `p1` is produced and gets consumed `c(p1, r2)` on second request `r2`. The second abort `a(?)` is ignored, because no unanswered request happened before. The third request `r3` has to wait on the next produced element `p2` and is not aborted till `p2` is produced. Thus, `p2` is consumed `c(p2, r3)` immediately after it got produced.

How can I achieve this in RxJS?

**Edit:**
I created an [example](http://jsbin.com/zihiceguce/1/edit?js,output) with a QUnit test on jsbin. You can edit the function `createConsume(produce, request, abort)` to try/test your solution.

The example contains the function definition of the [previously accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28756459/1065654).

Comment: Nice problem. [Here](http://jsbin.com/havoroniqi/3/edit) is my attempt, but @Brandon's is way better.

Comment: Btw. I noticed some small issues with your tests: 1. you produce `1`, `2`, but expect: `p1`, `p2`; 2. you once swapped `expected` and `actual`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I build this test in a hurry and shared the jsbin example the wrong way. Thus, I accidentally changed it later during my own approaches. I changed the elements to their original values: produce: `p1` and `p2`; request: `r1`, `r2` and `r3`; abort: `a1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution ignores aborts that don't follow an unanswered request:

```
const {merge} = Rx.Observable;

Rx.Observable.prototype.wrapValue = function(wrapper) {
    wrapper = (wrapper || {});
    return this.map(function (value) {
        wrapper.value = value;
        return wrapper;
    });
};

function createConsume(produce, request, abort) {
  return merge(
            produce.wrapValue({type: 'produce'}),
            request.wrapValue({type: 'request'}),
            abort.wrapValue({type: 'abort'})
         )
         .scan(
            [false, []],
            ([isRequest, products], e) => {
                // if last time the request was answered
                if (isRequest && products.length) {
                    // remove consumed product
                    products.shift();
                    // mark request as answered
                    isRequest = false;
                }
                if (e.type === 'produce') {
                    // save product to consume later
                    products.push(e.value);
                } else {
                    // if evaluated to false, e.type === 'abort'
                    isRequest = (e.type === 'request');
                }
                return [isRequest, products];
            }
         )
         .filter( ([isRequest, products]) => (isRequest && products.length) )
         .map( ([isRequest, products]) => products[0] ); // consume
}
```

[Code](http://jsbin.com/vejuvuvude/2/edit?js,output) in newest test on JSBin.

Answer (score 3):

This (core idea minus details) passes your JSBin test:

```
var consume = request
  .zip(abort.merge(produce), (r,x) => [r,x])
  .filter(([r,x]) => isNotAbort(x))
  .map(([r,p]) => p);
```

And the [JSBin code](http://jsbin.com/kiluxojusu/1/edit?js,output).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, although it doesn't behave like I'd like to. I edited my question to be more clear what behaviour I'd like to have. I edit the diagram, added a descriptio and a [link](http://jsbin.com/jotanilosi/2/edit?js,output) to a test example/environment on jsbin. I used your solution in that example. It fails because it skips the first produced element in favor of the second element, which gets consumed twice.

Comment: Updated my answer. Does this solve all your cases? @MegaMuetzenMike

Comment: Clever. I knew there had to be a way to do it with existing operators.

Comment: It's essentially "request combined with the corresponding [abort or produce], ignoring when the result was an abort".

Comment: It is so terse and elegant.

Comment: In the meantime, I realized that it would be much easier to use if aborts are ignored if no unanswered request happened before.

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite wrap my brain around how to do it with existing operators.  Here's how to do it with `Observable.create()`:

```
return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
  var rsub = new Rx.SingleAssignmentDisposable();
  var asub = new Rx.SingleAssignmentDisposable();
  var psub = new Rx.SingleAssignmentDisposable();
  var sub = new Rx.CompositeDisposable(rsub, asub, psub);
  var rq = [];
  var pq = [];
  var completeCount = 0;
  var complete = function () {
    if (++completeCount === 2) {
      observer.onCompleted();
    }
  };
  var consume = function () {
    if (pq.length && rq.length) {
      var p = pq.shift();
      var r = rq.shift();
      observer.onNext('p' + p);
    }
  };

  rsub.setDisposable(request.subscribe(
    function (r) {
      rq.push(r);
      consume();
    },
    function (e) { observer.onError(e); },
    complete));

  asub.setDisposable(abort.subscribe(
    function (a) {
      rq.shift();
    },
    function (e) { observer.onError(e); }
  ));

  psub.setDisposable(produce.subscribe(
    function (p) {
      pq.push(p);
      consume();
    },
    function (e) { observer.onError(e); },
    complete));


  return sub;
});
```

http://jsbin.com/zurepesijo/1/

Comment: Nice approach. Just would like to confirm: does calling `sub.dispose()` dispose all `Rx.SingleAssignmentDisposable`s?

Comment: Yes CompositeDisposable lets you group multiple disposables into a single disposable.